# Ant: зачем что-то еще?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, ant, build-automation

Иногда (редко но все же) пишу что-либо на Java и всегда использовал для сборки проектов Ant. Но уже давно знаю, что есть также и Maven, и Gradle. Чем эти системы сборки лучше или хуже по сравнению с Ant? Как-то пробовал разобраться с Maven, но пока не осилил, тоже самое с Gradle - не понимаю в чем фишка этих систем по сравнению со старым добрым Ant.

Comment: Потому что нет в мире совершенства

Comment: в чем фишка Ant по сравнению со старыми добрыми bat-файлами и bash-скриптами?

Answer (score 5):

Не знаю насчет Maven, не доводилось работать, но Gradle на 10 порядков более мощная система сборки, чем Ant.
Конечно, если вы не используете какие то специфические алгоритмы сборки с несколькими вариантами билдинга, не подключаете внешние библиотеки, которые находятся в сетевых репозиториях или еще в каких то местах и разнообразных форматах, работаете не в команде, у вас не 3 варианта приложения с немного различающимся функционалом и прочие изыски, а только билдите одно собственное приложение в релиз - вам и кажется, что разницы нет, но хотя бы один факт, что Gradle использует полноценный язык программирования Groovy для создания сценария сборки, то есть вы можете написать полноценную программу, как, из чего и при каких условиях собирать определенный билд, уже выводит его на абсолютно другой уровень по сравнению с примитивным языком Ant.

В общем то довольно доступно о качестенных различиях той или иной системы сборки и предоствляемых ими возможностях можно прочитать на той же википедии. Более подробно в официальной документации.

Отвлеченно, разница между Ant и Gradle  находится в таких соотношениях, как управление автомобилем и запуск космического корабля. Вполне возможно, что ваш проект не предполагает настолько глобальных действий, как "вывод на орбиту" (хотя Grable способен ее решить), но и управление "таксопарком" с Ant уже определенная проблема, а это вполне "земная" задача.